# How to change IsPassive="true" to false in travelocity (saml test 2.0) with WSO2 IS

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am getting by default IsPassive="true" in saml request which is not allowing to test further. Can anyone please let me know how to disable it?

Sample Request & response

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="XXXXXX"
                    Destination="XXXX/samlsso"
                    ForceAuthn="false"
                    ID="0"
                    IsPassive="true"
                    IssueInstant="2017-11-14T04:33:32.667Z"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    Version="2.0"
                    >
    <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">XXX_SIT</samlp:Issuer>
    <saml2p:NameIDPolicy xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                         AllowCreate="true"
                         Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
                         SPNameQualifier="Issuer"
                         />
    <saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                                  Comparison="exact"
                                  >
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>



<saml2p:Response Destination="XXXXX"
                 ID="makcbhpbkmpgheepeaibnbmolnhalmdchlpfjiij"
                 InResponseTo="0"
                 IssueInstant="2017-11-14T04:33:31.297Z"
                 Version="2.0"
                 xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 >
    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
                  xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                  >localhost</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder">
            <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:NoPassive" />
        </saml2p:StatusCode>
        <saml2p:StatusMessage>Cannot authenticate Subject in Passive Mode</saml2p:StatusMessage>
    </saml2p:Status>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the passive request from a config but you can bypass it if you directly access the `http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/index.jsp` page.

In travelocity, the passive authentication request is sent while accessing the root context of the app e.g: `http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com`. The purpose of this call is to check whether the user already has an authenticated session with the IS. If the user has an authenticated session, IS will return a SAML response with an assertion and travelocity will be redirected to home.jsp. If the user doesn't have an authecticated session,  IS will return the SAML response you have mentioned above ("Cannot authenticate Subject in Passive Mode"). Once travelocity receives this response it should be redirected to index.jsp where you will have different options to authenticate with SAML.

The login options you see there doesn't use passive SAML authentication requests.